# Open property window of a folder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, system, controlpanel

I'm creating a custom folder browser in WPF, and there is a requirement to open the folder's property window directly from the application itself.

I know there is something called .cpl file which we can use in a C# program to open the window in a new process by using this code: `Process.Start("desk.cpl");` [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/149648/description-of-control-panel-cpl-files). However, I'd like to know the name of *.cpl* which we can use to open the property window of the folder. Would appreciate if someone shares how I can achieve this functionality in C# code. 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that whole Windows UI consists of `.cpl` files?